# When using the Milvus standalone server, is is possible to get metrics?

Tags: vector-database, milvus

The [Milvus documentation](https://milvus.io/docs/visualize.md#Prerequisites) states that metrics are available, but I've only seen examples of it working with the K8S deployment, and I'm using the standalone server. Is it possible to get metrics from the standalone deployment?